# Do not add "," after last field in CSV

Tags: python, csv

```
f=open('students.csv', 'r') 
a=f.readline() 
length=len(a.split(","))
fw=open('output.csv', 'w')
lst = []
while a: 
   lst.append(a)
   a=f.readline()

for counter in range(length):
    for item in lst:
        x = len(item.split(","))
        if x == length:
            x = item.split(",")
```

1. #here i want if condition to check whether it is the last element of row and add","?

   ```
           fw.write(x[counter].split("\n")[0]+",")
   ```
2. #elif the condition that it is the last element of each row to not add ","?

```
    fw.write("\n")
fw.close() 
f.close()
```

Comment: Do you have a reason for not using the csv module?

Comment: Yes, i must not use module and transpose of pandas. I have converted the columns to rows but it is adding a comma after every element and i don't want that in the last element of each row

Comment: The `csv` module is distinct from Pandas and is part of the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

`join` will be your friend here, if you cannot use the `csv` module:

```
for counter in range(length):
    fw.write(','.join(x[counter] for x in (item.split(',') for item in lst)))
    fw.write('\n')
```

But you should first strip the end of line characters:

```
a=f.readline().strip()
length=len(a.split(","))
fw=open('output.csv', 'w')
lst = []
while a: 
   lst.append(a)
   a=f.readline().strip()
```

But your code is neither Pythonic nor efficient.

You split the same string in every iteration of counter, when you could have splitted it once at read time. Next for iterating the lines of a text file, the Pythonic way is to iterate the file. And finaly, `with` ensure that the files will be properly closed at the end of the block. Your code could become:

```
with open('students.csv', 'r')  as f, open('output.csv', 'w') as fw
    lst = [a.strip().split(',') for a in f]
    counter = len(lst[0])
    for counter in range(length):
        fw.write(','.join(x[counter] for x in (item for item in lst)))
        fw.write('\n')
```